# Adding a series of input number in c++

Tags: c++

Hi can anyone help me in creating a code for the sum of input number in C++.
e.g.

Input: 535
Output: 13

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
int i = 0,sum = 0;
int numarray[50];

void calc(int c,string num) {
  do {
    numarray[i] = num.at(i);
    /*sum = sum + numarray[i];*/
    sum = sum + num.at(i);
    cout << numarray[i] << endl;
    i++;
  } while(i != c);
  cout << sum << endl;
}

int main() {
  string num;
  int i,charlen;
  int numar[50];
  int sum=0;

  cout << "Input numbers: ";
  cin >> num;

  charlen = num.length();

  calc(charlen,num);
}
```

Comment: Here is my script for that but there is a problem i output

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=URiCNXjH)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you read in the numbers? Can you add them> Can you print the result? Which step is giving you trouble? And don't post a link to your code, post the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

While characters are numbers, their values are often not the same as the character they represent. The most common encoding scheme is [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/).

As you can see in the linked table, the digits don't have the value `1` or `2` etc. Instead they have values like `49` and `50` etc. The characters `'5'` and `'3'` have the ASCII values `53` and `51` respectively, adding e.g. `"535"` will give you the result `157`.

But as you can see in the ASCII table, all numbers are consecutive, that means we can use a very simple trick to get the digits value from its ASCII value, simply subtract the ASCII value of `'0'`. For example `'5' - '0'` will give you the value `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   unsigned long long x;

   std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number: ";
   std::cin >> x;

   unsigned long long sum = 0;

   do { sum += x % 10; } while ( x /= 10 );

   std::cout << "\nThe sum of digits of the number is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand this. :)

Comment: can you explain the do-while part please?

Comment: @user3585505 You sequentially get the last digit after dividing the number by 10.

Comment: how about unsigned long long, what is this mean? sorry im just started to learning this.

Comment: @user3585505 it is an integral type similar to undigned int. Only it is larger in size and can keep more decimal digits. You should read any book for beginners on C++.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability, it might help to not pass in the charlength into the function, and just do that inside the method. Besides that, a for loop seems like a better option in this case as well.

```
void calc(string num) {
    int sum = 0, int i = 0;
    //for loop run from num.length - 1 to 0 {
       /*numarray[i] = stoi(num.at(i));*/
        /*sum = sum + numarray[i];*/
        sum = sum + stoi(num.at(i));
        cout << numarray[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
   cout << sum << endl;
}
```